# Mongodb java input date between two date fields

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to create a query such as :

> SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE  {MY_DATE_1} BETWEEN {DB_COLUMN_1} AND
>   {DB_COLUMN_2} OR  {MY_DATE_2} BETWEEN {DB_COLUMN_1} AND {DB_COLUMN_2})

I know how to do the opposite ( a field between two variables), since BasicDBObject takes a string (I guess the field name) as first parameter and not a date. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guss   you  want to  use  `$or`  to  query  like  the sql

here is the demo with java

```
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        BasicDBObject condition1 = new BasicDBObject("fieldA",new BasicDBObject("$gt","2018-06-02 12:20:00").append("$lt","2019-06-02 12:20:00"));
        BasicDBObject condition2 = new BasicDBObject("fieldB",new BasicDBObject("$gt","2018-06-02 12:20:00").append("$lt","2019-06-02 12:20:00"));

        BasicDBList condList = new BasicDBList();
        condList.add(condition1);
        condList.add(condition2);
        query.put("$or" ,condList);

        collection.find(query);
```

the  `$gt` means  greater than  and  `$lt`  means   less than .